# How to redirect to Paypal Philippines?

Tags: redirect, paypal

My developer made me a code but during payment redirection to Paypal, it redirects to Paypal USA.  I want to redirect it to Paypal Philippines.  My developer said that the following code should be changed but he does not know the parameter for Paypal Philippines:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US" />
```

I hope someone can help, thank you.

Comment: Try with ph for philippines

Comment: lc codes are standardized so you can look them up. However, just want to note that this may or may not do what you want. There are two nationalities (at least) in play for any payment, the buyer's (sender's) country and the seller's (receiver's) country. The LC parameter is just a suggestion that PayPal "guess" the buyer's country's may be of the given locale; this is mainly useful so that if your site is in (e.g. French) the first PayPal page should display in French. The payment will actually be governed by the countries of the actual buyer and the seller.